# Jquery click event stops working after content is updated with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, crash, show-hide

My application crashes when I try to hide an element which has dynamic content (ie. users list)

the element i'm trying to show and hide looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="group">Users</a>
<ul id="staff">
 <li>User1</li>
 <li>user2</li>
</ul>
```

The jquery code I'm using is:

```
$('.group').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Users are updated frequently with an ajax call ( the li has a lot more content than just a name).

I've been searching for answers but none of the results seem to fix my problem,
I've tried using several ways of hiding/unhiding the element, using `$(document).on('click', '.group', function(){})` instead of `.click()`, disabling the `.click()` event untill the ajax call has completed, even with a timeOut of 3sec..

this is my Ajax, using ajaxQueue plugin

```
 working = true;
$.ajaxQueue({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './api/users'
}).done(function(r)
{
            $('#staff').empty(); 
    $.each(r, function(i)
    {
        var addnew = $('<li>').addClass('ind-bg');
  var newDiv = $('<div>').addClass('ind').appendTo(addnew);
    $('<img>').attr('src', r[i].picture).addClass('userPicture').appendTo(newDiv);
    $('<i>').addClass('batch status'+r[i].status).attr('data-icon', '').appendTo(newDiv);
    $('<span>').html(r[i].firstName + ' ' + r[i].name).appendTo(newDiv);
    addnew.appendTo($('#staff'));
    })
setTimeout(function(){working = false}, 3000);
})
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated... :)

Comment: _"My application crashes"_ in what way? are you getting errors? is the browser actually crashing?

Comment: _timeOut of 3sec_...is it in your ajax call? like `timeout: 3000,`

Comment: The browser window stops responding, then returns the message that the page has crashed

Comment: share your ajax implementation!

Comment: no, in my .done function, i had a var 'working' which is set to true when an ajax call is working, then set to false again after it's done

Comment: How many elements are in the UL? if there are tons it will take a while for the code to hide them, and may even crash if its too many.

Comment: I have added my ajax call, the li has 4 elements in it, 1 div, image, <i> and span

Comment: sorry, the UL has about 3 at the moment, but can ofcourse get bigger when there are more users

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //make what you want to hide
    });
    $(document).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
       //make what you want to show
    });
});
```